# Youtube Channel Last 30 day and views count

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Hi I want to attract the last 30 day views of the channels with youtube apis but somehow I could not. Does anyone have an idea?

I've tried it with Youtube Analytics api, but it only values "channel == mine". that is not.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code we need an example then descirbe any issues you are having with your example

Comment: I want to list the number of views of Youtube channels in the last 7 days and the last 30 days.

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: What have you tried please show me your code I would be happy to test it

Comment: query: [link](http://prntscr.com/kx8ju3) 
result: [link](http://prntscr.com/kx8k4k)

What I really want to do is this; the number of views of the channel I want to take.

"channel == MINE" do not receive the error, but I get an error when I enter the id of a different channel.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube analytics Data is private data.   Inorder to see the data for a channel you must be authenticated as the owner of that channel.

YouTube authorization is also channel based if you are having issues seeing one of your channels logout of your application and authenticate it again make sure to select the proper channel when promoted

Comment: I'm very pleased if you can give some insight about how some of the sites that do the things I wanted to do.

Comment: What sites would that be?   You can't access private analytics data of someone else channel.   You can't access data you don't own.

Comment: Example: [link](https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/eminemmusic) 
As it appears on the site, the number of daily views is written. That's exactly what I need.